# How to I remove "Managed by your organization" from Google Chrome and Chromium

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, security, chromium

I noticed both Google Chrome and Chromium show "Managed by your organization" at the bottom of the 3 dots / hamburger menu. This is a personal computer--nothing to do with work. How do I get my browsers "un-managed" / get rid of the policies?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit Dekstop. Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88-1. Chromium 79.0.3945.79-0.

I tried `sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable` and re-installed, but the "Managed..." notice and policies are still there.

[image: google chrome hamburger menu screenshot]

[image: google chrome policies page screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
sudo mv --verbose --target-directory=/tmp /etc/chromium /etc/chromium-browser /etc/opt/chrome ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/chromium
```

Ignore warnings from the `mv` about non-existant source files. Then, restart Google Chrome and/or Chromium.

This completely "un-manages" the browsers.

Updated with content from other answers below, including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206743/2273) in an attempt to build one complete answer.

Comment: WARNING! This solution will erase your current profile and you'll lose all your open tabs.

Comment: The issue will keep coming back unless you identify the root cause. Not practical to completely reset Chrome every time it gets hijacked. See @vasiljevski answer and remove the offending policy.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest way was just to find the policy definition and edit/remove it, depending on the need.

In my case I found it in `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed`
since it is a simple JSON format it can be edited easily.

But before you do this, check with your organization if you are allowed to edit the policis.

Answer (score -1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197609/how-to-i-remove-managed-by-your-organization-from-google-chrome-and-chromium/1197611#1197611) did not seem to work or apply.

Also, as others have indicated, I tried it too and uninstalling and reinstalling Google Chrome will NOT work, as the "Managed" and "policy" settings are stored elsewhere. They may be stored in multiple sub-folders named "Managed Extension Settings" or "Policy", for instance, here: **/home/MY_USERNAME/.config/google-chrome**.

So, to remove them, simply rename the folder to something else:

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome.bak
```

Then close and re-open the Chrome browser. It will require you to sign in to your account and sync settings all over again, but once done you will no longer see the "Managed by your organization" indicator in the top-right menu, and the following browser page will now be clear, as shown here. Notice the 3 places it now says "No policies set":

**chrome://policy**

[image]

## Additional Reading:

1. https://www.howtogeek.com/410106/why-does-chrome-say-its-managed-by-your-organization/

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I improved my answer above by incorporating yours (I hope this is an acceptable practice on askubuntu). I have not tested extensively but I suspect both parts are necessary for a complete answer, and it shouldn't hurt to move all directories to `/tmp` then try restarting chrome and/or chromium.

Comment: Borrowing answers is fine as long as you cite and link back to them. That's always the right thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

Following steps will resolve the issue

Step 1. Open Google Chrome web browser and type `chrome://flags/` in address bar and press Enter. It'll open the advanced configuration page.

[image]

Step 2. Now type `managed` in the "`Search flags`" box.

Step 3. Go to the following option:

```
Show managed UI for managed users
```

Step 4. To disable/remove the "Managed by your organization" message in Chrome, select `Disabled` from the drop-down box.

Step 5. Google Chrome will ask you to restart the browser. Click on "`Relaunch now`" button to restart Google Chrome.

Step 5. Now try to open the main menu or Settings page in Chrome and you'll no longer see "Managed by your organization" message. It'll disappear completely.

Comment: This hides the problem... I want to _remove_ the policies completely so the browser is once again un-managed.

Comment: Disabling the `Show managed UI for managed users` is the recommended method for doing so. Removing `/etc/chromium` `/etc/chromium-browser` `/etc/opt/chrome` `/tmp` can cause **Unpredictabe damage**

Comment: Recommended by whom? What kind of damage? And check out my fix again please: `/tmp` is the destination folder.